# Why is INT_MAX & x = x?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit, and-operator

While doing the question ANDROUND on spoj, I wanted to write the query function for my segment tree. There in the situation when l, r are out of range i need to return a number which while doing the BITWISE AND operation, would not change the answer.

In one of the solutions, I observed that bitwise AND of any number with INT_MAX will return us the number itself.

Why is this so?

Comment: `INT_MAX` presumably is `1111111...`, right? So it will never switch any bits *off* in whatever it's AND'd with.

Comment: no, it won't return the same values for negative numbers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because INT_MAX is a number that is represented only by 1's. for 32-bit int, it is represented by the bit sequence `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111`. Now, the `&` operator, checks if both numbers have a value of 1 at some index (For example, if both numbers have a value of 1 at index 5, the result will have a value of 1 at index 5). If that is the case, the result will have a value of 1 in that index, otherwise, it will store a value of 0 in that index of the result.

So if you consider the INT MAX number - which again, is the bit sequence `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111` and the number 2, for example, which is represented by the bit sequence `00000000 00000000 00000000 00000010`. Only in the 2nd smallest index, there is a 1 in both numbers so only there the result will have 1, and 0 everywhere else.

### Horizontal visualization

`11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111`

&

`00000000 00000000 00000000 00000010`

=

`00000000 00000000 00000000 00000010`

Comment: INT_MAX would be `01111111 11111111...` and not `11111111 11111111...`